# linux redhat 7 ( or centos 7 ) + firewalld mask the firewall

Tags: linux, rhel, iptables, firewall, services

I want to block the user to start the firewall on Linux machines
so I want to use mask on servers as the following:

```
systemctl mask firewalld
```

regarding that, I have few questions.

I see that when mask the firewall service its creates a symbolic link of the `firewall.service` to  `/dev/null`, thus disabling the service.

So where is the location of the service that point to `/dev/null` (Path of the service that point to `/dev/null`)?

second

Masking the firewall is nice option to block users to start the firewall service, but as all know user can do unmask and then start the service.

Any advice on if we have other strong option from mask?

Comment: [Quick & effective post optimization checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291370/1783163). I think it would be useful for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand the question, the users you are talking about have root access (since they can unmask a service). In this case there's nothing you can do. If you want your users not to enable a service, don't give them privileged access.

About your first point, the firewalld service is defined in `/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service`.

Comment: so  what about the location of the service that point to /dev/null ( PATH of the service that point to /dev/null )

Comment: I answered in the post above.  If it helped you please consider accepting the answer. This will mark your question as solved for future readers, and will also prevent closure & deletion of your question.